# How to auto-populate a names list to one sheet based on data in another sheet in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula, excel-2016

I searched the other pages that seemed to be answering the question. I have tried to do this using the if-then formula between sheets, but it doesn't work well with multiple cells / columns. I can't figure it out.

I saw somewhere that a person suggested a query (but that was for use in Google and doesn't work in Excel). Any suggestions on how to best do this?

I am trying to create a consultant database in Excel. We use consultants on projects, and various consultants perform X number of jobs.

**Sheet 1 would be the master list with the following data**

A1 - Company Name

B1 - Specialty 1

C1 - Specialty 2

D1 - Specialty 3

(and so forth - probably up to 10 specialties), Then

L1 - Key Contacts

M1 - Email 1

N1 - Email 2

O1 - Email 3

P1 - Email 4

Q1 - Previous Projects

and so on (there may be cell phone numbers and more added)

**Sheet 2 and beyond would populate based on specialty.**

Let's say Sheet 2 is called Architects.  If one of the specialties matches "Architect", I'd want it to provide me the following on the Architects sheet (sheet 2):

A1 Company Name

B1 Key Contacts

C1 Email1

D1 Email2

E1 Email3

F1 Email4

G1 Previous Projects

Can someone please help me figure out how to auto populate? As the master sheet changes, it will be imperative I don't have to constantly update the other sheets.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question (this is not a "code for me" site), can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Done. Not looking for free coding. Looking for specific suggestions to approach.

Comment: Do you have a "master list" sheet for each "company", or does "A1" mean "row 1", etc?

Comment: Dang it... Editing.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Ahh - that data layout looks more usable! (I hate sheets which have fields in rows instead of columns. My brain doesn't work that way. :D)

Comment: Your problem with auto-populating this is that you are going to have to handle not just the case when someone enters "Architect" into (for instance) cell C5 (at which time you need the information from row 5 copied to the Architect sheet) but also the case when someone changes cell E10 from "Architect" to "Designer" (at which time you need to update the Architect sheet to remove the information for this company, and update the Designer sheet to add the information).  It is going to be much easier to just recreate all the "specialty" sheets after all updates in one editing session are completed

Comment: Or, alternatively, why not just create the "specialty" sheet when someone wants the information.  I.e. have a single sheet (in addition to the master sheet) where the user enters the speciality that they are interested in (perhaps in cell A1) and then a `Worksheet_Change` event then takes that information and populates the sheet with details of companies matching that speciality.

Comment: This sounds like it'd be best to use MS Access instead

Comment: @Maldred LOL - any time someone says "I am trying to create a xyz database in Excel", that's the first thing I think of too.

Comment: @YowE3K With all the back and forth of data with this question, it seems most fitting... However sometimes it's not always available unfortunately lol

Comment: @YowE3K I will probably have drop down lists in the Specialty columns

Comment: Whether the value is changed via the user typing something in, or by the user selecting something via a drop-down list, doesn't really affect the fact that the value has changed and the old value is no longer applicable and the new value is.

Comment: I think there should be some kind of a thing where I can say "if B1, C1, D1, E1, F1 = Architect, then_______" but not sure that works with a separate sheet, and how to tell it to add the information I require. Another board suggested this query, which only works in Google Docs:    =query(Sheet1!;B2:G2"select A where B='Architect' OR C='Architect' OR D='Architect' OR E='Architect' OR F=Architect";1)

Comment: Also @YowE3K, if the data on the master sheet is accurate, and the formula or code is correct in each row of subsequent sheets, then is data changes on the master sheet, each subsequent sheet should change, accordingly, correct? I guess it would create too many blank lines, where none of the requested data exists,,, ugh...  perhaps Access is the correct tool. I just hate it. I prefer FM Pro

Comment: You could certainly write an SQL query to do that against your master list, but my main question is why you would want to do that **before** someone looks at the other sheets?  ("If a tree falls in a forest, and no-one is there, does it make a sound?", i.e. what does it matter what is on the "Architect" sheet unless someone wants to look at it?)  When someone wants to know what architects there are, provide the information to them at that time.

Comment: The master list is there in no particular order (as it is entered) and many consultants do a myriad of things, "architect of record," "architectural design" "feasibility studies" etc... There would be sheets for each of those, so when we need to send an RFP to all of the vendors who provide feasibility studies, we go to that sheet.

Comment: All I am suggesting is that, when you want to send an RFP to all of the vendors who provide feasibility studies, you type in "Feasibility Studies" (or, preferably, select that from a drop-down) and let the macro give you back a list of all the people that do feasibility studies.  Don't try to produce the list before it is needed - it gets too complicated.

Comment: I missed where you said to do a macro. I have a master list started, just haven't gotten feedback as to whether it requires more information (i.e. cell phone numbers etc). I am confused though. Where would you put the macro? I like the idea of just having a macro on the main sheet, with a drop down - and when "feasability study" is selected, it auto filters only those who have that in their row... Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also - to your question about when someone updates the master sheet... I'm still not clear how, if the Architect sheet has the coding that is looking for architects.... if someone changes cell E2 from Architect to Designer, how that wouldn't be reflected and automatically change the "Architect" sheet?  Do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: I would have a master list sheet, and a "Query" sheet.  On the "Query" sheet, I would let the user choose something in cell A1 (or wherever looks nice) and then have a `Worksheet_Change` event in the "Query" sheet that does something if cell A1 is changed.  The "something" could probably be something as simple as looping through every row on the master sheet and, if it finds the value from A1 in columns B:K of the master sheet, copy the info from that row of the master list to the "Query" sheet in the next available row.

Comment: ahhhh... I like that!!! I knew this was the right place! Now to research how to do a query sheet! LOL

Comment: It is almost impossible to have formulas that will populate values on a sheet that picks values from another sheet and not leave blank rows.  (Sure the Architect sheet could have a formula in A2 which says `=IF(OR(Master!B2="Architect",Master!C2="Architect",Master!D2="Architect",...,Master!K2="Architect"),Master!A2,"")` but I think you want the first row in the Architect sheet to have the first **matching** row from the master list, and the second row in the Architect sheet to have the second **matching** row, etc.)

Comment: This should move to chat, and once resolved, please post an answer here as I'd love to see what the end result is

Comment: Will do... I am still working with our IT solutions at my office however, to enable my use of queries, and external database solutions. If/when I have resolved what I'm doing, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Potential "Query" sheet `Worksheet_Change` event (i.e. this code should be pasted into the code module of the actual sheet you use for the "querying"):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo ReEnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim Speciality As String
    Speciality = Range("A1").Value
    'clear existing data
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 2 Then ' Assume headings are on row 2
        Rows("3:" & lastRow).ClearContents
    End If
    'find new data
    newRow = 2
    With Worksheets("MasterList")
        For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For c = 2 To 11 ' loop through the speciality columns
                If .Cells(r, c).Value = Speciality Then
                    newRow = newRow + 1
                    Cells(newRow, "A").Value = .Cells(r, "A").Value
                    Cells(newRow, "B").Value = .Cells(r, "L").Value
                    Cells(newRow, "C").Value = .Cells(r, "M").Value
                    Cells(newRow, "D").Value = .Cells(r, "N").Value
                    Cells(newRow, "E").Value = .Cells(r, "O").Value
                    Cells(newRow, "F").Value = .Cells(r, "P").Value
                    Cells(newRow, "G").Value = .Cells(r, "Q").Value                        
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
ReEnableEvents:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This assumes that cell A1 of the "Query" sheet is the value you want to look for (i.e. the "Speciality"), that row 2 of that sheet will have headings, and that rows 3 onward will be populated with the results.

I haven't tested it, but it should be close to what you need.

Comment: Note:  I have no idea whether all that code is valid on the Mac version of Excel.  It seems fairly basic, so I don't **think** you would have any problems with it.